# MATLAB generate all ways that n items can be put into m bins?

Tags: matlab, combinations, vectorization, permutation

I want to find all ways that `n` items can be split among `m` bins. For example, for `n=3` and `m=3` the output would be (the order doesn't matter):

```
[3 0 0
 0 3 0
 0 0 3
 2 1 0
 1 2 0
 0 1 2
 0 2 1
 1 0 2
 2 0 1
 1 1 1]
```

The algorithm should be as efficient as possible, preferrably vectorized/using inbuilt functions rather than `for` loops. Thank you!

Comment: @SomeGuy That's the total number of combinations. Could you enumerate these all? Not an accusation. I'm just genuinely curious.

Comment: The objective is to obtain all the arrangements, not how many arrangements there could be.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, enumerating all is not so easy after all !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be pretty efficient.

It works by generating all posible splitings of the real interval [0, *n*] at *m*−1 integer-valued, possibly coincident split points. The lengths of the resulting subintervals give the solution.

For example, for `n=4` and `m=3`, some of the possible ways to split the interval [0, 4] at *m*−1 points are:

- Split at `0`, `0`: this gives subintervals of lenghts `0`, `0`, `4`.
- Split at `0`, `1`: this gives subintervals of lenghts `0`, `1`, `3`.
- ...
- Split at `4`, `4`: this gives subintervals of lenghts `4`, `0`, `0`.

Code:

```
n = 4; % number of items
m = 3; % number of bins
x = bsxfun(@minus, nchoosek(0:n+m-2,m-1), 0:m-2); % split points
x = [zeros(size(x,1),1) x n*ones(size(x,1),1)]; % add start and end of interval [0, n]
result = diff(x.').'; % compute subinterval lengths
```

The result is in lexicographical order.

As an example, for `n = 4` items in `m = 3` bins the output is

```
result =
     0     0     4
     0     1     3
     0     2     2
     0     3     1
     0     4     0
     1     0     3
     1     1     2
     1     2     1
     1     3     0
     2     0     2
     2     1     1
     2     2     0
     3     0     1
     3     1     0
     4     0     0
```

Comment: Very very nice!

Comment: Very elegant ! Took me some serious brainpower to understand what is going on :)

Comment: @SomeGuy Yes, it's easier to write it than to read it :-) I've added an example that should make things clearer

Comment: Thank you, this is very nice!

Comment: But wait, your `nchoosek` will return (n+2)C(m-1) combinations(which will eventually give the split) where by theory there should be (n+m-1)C(m-1) ways to split, have the examples worked out just because these cases have `m - 1 = 2` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a solution based on an external function and `accumarray` (it should work starting R2015a because of [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)):

```
n = uint8(4); % number of items
m = uint8(3); % number of bins
whichBin = VChooseKR(1:m,n).'; % see FEX link below. Transpose saves us a `reshape()` later.
result = accumarray([repelem(1:size(whichBin,2),n).' whichBin(:)],1);
```

Where [`VChooseKR(V,K)`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26277-vchoosekr) creates a matrix whose rows are all combinations created by choosing `K` elements of the vector `V` with repetitions.

#### Explanation:

The output of `VChooseKR(1:m,n)` for `m=3` and `n=4` is:

```
 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     2
 1     1     1     3
 1     1     2     2
 1     1     2     3
 1     1     3     3
 1     2     2     2
 1     2     2     3
 1     2     3     3
 1     3     3     3
 2     2     2     2
 2     2     2     3
 2     2     3     3
 2     3     3     3
 3     3     3     3
```

All we need to do now is "histcount" the numbers on each row using positive integer bins to get the desired result. The first output row would be `[4 0 0]` because all 4 elements go in the 1<sup>st</sup> bin. The second row would be `[3 1 0]` because 3 elements go in the 1<sup>st</sup> bin and 1 in the 2<sup>nd</sup>, etc.

Comment: the third line should read `VChooseKR(1:m,double(n)).';` to work (at least for me). Also, this method for some reason fails for large `n`, `m` values. For instance if `n=6` and `m=6` then for some reason `result(end,:)` is `0   241   251   252   252   252`

Comment: @space_voyager for the small example of the OP, uint8 is sufficient, but for n, m resulting in more combinations, you might need uint16 or even more. I cannot test it at the moment, but it seems like a simple case of integer overflow.

Comment: Yup, just figured that out. Using `result = accumarray([repelem(1:size(whichBin,2),uint16(n)).' uint16(whichBin(:))],1);` works for larger n, m values